# What is a method to determine app health when dealing with continuous integration?

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently, my jenkinsfile is able to compile, deploy, and start the application on my CI box. But I've no window into if the app started correctly. Technically someone can add code that compiles but doesn't start; ie code was added to reference a config, but the person never updated the config file. I want to catch those types of issues that prevents the app from starting and send an email to the person.

How can I accomplish this?

Current app takes about ~3 minutes to start. When everything successfully starts, it'll output: Started Application in 166.125 seconds (JVM running for 175.714)

Comment: Do you have any UI or Unit tests?

Comment: yeah, but from what ive seen, soemtimes tests are skipped/crappy so everything will pass and it looks healthy from testing and the build. BUT when you try to start the app, it will fail due to something broken; like when the app is expecting a config but there's no default value